# scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive -> Set[Char] -> Set[String]?

Tags: scala

The following two commands create a `Set[Char]`, and then `map`-ing over it gives a `Set[String]`, as desired:

```
scala> ('a' to 'z').toSet
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(e, s, ...)

scala> res15.map(_.toString)
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(e, s, ...)
```

But why doesn't the following work?

```
scala> ('a' to 'z').toSet.map(_.toString)
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded 
     function ((x$1) => x$1.toString)('a' to 'z').toSet.map(_.toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative works perfectly:

```
 ('a' to 'z').toSet[Char].map(_.toString)
```

It happens because `toSet` accepts a `[B >: A]` type argument, and cannot directly infer the type on which to invoke `toString`